# Configuring geonode proxied by nginx on webfaction

Tags: geoserver, geonode

I'm trying to install geonode on webfaction. 
Webfaction doesn't provide root access, so it needs installation from source. 
I'm struggling to get authentication working.

Webfaction works like this (simplified a bit):

- using their control panel, create an "application". This reserves a port.
- also via control panel, create a "website". This maps a domain to this port. This happens via a system nginx instance which proxies all requests to the assigned port.

I created an **nginx** instance listening on this port, proxying to **geonode** (i.e. django, served using `uwsgi`) and **geoserver** (i.e. a `tomcat` webapp).

So the total setup is:

```
webfaction nginx -> my nginx -> / (django)
                             -> /geoserver/ (tomcat)
```

When loading the geonode homepage, tomcat logs as follows:

```
2014-05-08 05:49:06,865 WARN [geonode.security] - Error connecting to the GeoNode server for authentication purposes
org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationServiceException: Communication with GeoNode failed
        at org.geonode.security.GeoNodeAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(GeoNodeAuthenticationProvider.java:61)
[...]
Caused by: java.io.IOException: GeoNode communication failed, status report is: 404, Not Found
        at org.geonode.security.HTTPClient.sendGET(HTTPClient.java:73)
```

Here is my nginx config:

```
pid /home/.../geonode2_nginx/parts/nginx-geonode/nginx-geonode.pid;
lock_file /home/.../geonode2_nginx/parts/nginx-geonode/nginx-geonode.lock;
daemon off;
events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}
http {
    server {
        listen 9999;
        access_log /home/.../logs/user/access_geonode2_nginx.log;
        error_log /home/.../logs/user/error_geonode2_nginx.log;
        # serve staticfiles
        location /static/ {
            include       /home/.../geonode2_nginx/parts/nginx/conf/mime.types;
            alias /home/.../geonode2_static/;
            expires 7d;
        }
        # serve mediafiles, default 'uploaded' in GeoNode
        location /uploaded/ {
            alias /home/.../geonode2_upload/;
            expires 7d;
        }
        # geoserver proxy
        location /geoserver/ {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8888/geoserver/;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        }
        # gunicorn/uwsgi wsgi proxy
        location / {
            proxy_pass_header Server;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
            proxy_connect_timeout 20;
            proxy_read_timeout 20;
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:7777/;
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone see anything wrong?

Any tips on debugging this? What HTTP headers should I look for?

How can I find out what the 404 in the tomcat message above refers to?

I asked this question on the webfaction forums also at 
https://community.webfaction.com/questions/16732/geonode-configuration

Comment: I patched geonode's `geoserver-geonode-ext` to [log the URL](https://github.com/jean/geoserver-geonode-ext/commit/11c3c75989d05ce7f1dbb5da211b13b14a4af3ad)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The direct cause of the issue that I was experiencing was a configuration issue, addressed in this documentation patch:

https://github.com/GeoNode/geonode/commit/cc732e0a73c6d04d8f57fdf376dfb9a9848abd86